# limits $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e-(1+x)^{1/x}}{x},\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\log n} (n^{1/n}-1).$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find the following limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e-(1+x)^{1/x}}{x},$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\log n} (n^{1/n}-1).$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Three posts in a minute? Can you please show your work and thoughts? Also, it helps readability to format using MathJax (see FAQ). regards

Comment: hint for #1: do you know a series expansion for $(1+x)^{1/x}$? what about for $\frac1x\log(1+x)$?

Comment: I've edited your post, but I'm not completely sure that I've done the second one correctly (it's a bit ambiguous in your post where does $(n^{1/n}-1)$ go). Please, see if it needs correcting.

Answer (score 2):

By Taylor series we have

$$\frac{e-(1+x)^{1/x}}{x}=\frac{e-\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\log(1+x)\right)}{x}\\
=e\frac{1-\exp(-\frac{x}{2}+O(x))}{x}=\frac{e}{2}+O(x)$$
and

$$n^{1/n}=\exp(\frac{\log(n)}{n})=1+\frac{\log(n)}{n}+o\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)$$
so
$$\frac{n}{\log n} \left(n^{1/n}-1\right)=1+o(1)$$